# Python, Django: ValueError: unsupported format character '(' (0x28) at index 3

Tags: python, django, translation, string-formatting

Can somebody explain to me why this raises a ValueError? (using Python 2.7)

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

...

template = _('► %(user)s, random text here @[%(friend_id)s] more random text ◄◄◄'.decode('utf-8')) % {'user': friend_profile.user.first_name, 'friend_id': user.id}
```

This is the error (sent by celery error email):

```
  File "/var/www/myapp/apps/app/tasks.py", line 54, in notify_friends_new_invite
    template=_('��� %(user)s, random text here @[%(friend_id)s] more random text ���������'.decode('utf-8')) % {'user': friend_profile.user.first_name, 'friend_id': user.id},
ValueError: unsupported format character '(' (0x28) at index 3
```

Comment: Can't reproduce that. I do get a SyntaxError, caused by an extra close paren after `decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: Does work for me (from `manage.py shell`)

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Did you include the opening `_(`? I cannot reproduce this either though. I wonder what codec the source file was saved with.

Comment: What happens if you replace the `►` character in your source code with `\xe2\x96\xba`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters ah, true, with that it works fine.

Comment: Do you have a message catalog with a value for this entry? Your string works just fine *without* translation. What does `print _('► %(user)s, random text here @[%(friend_id)s] more random text ◄◄◄'.decode('utf-8'))` show (so *no* interpolation, just translation).

Comment: Martijn: The source file is utf8 and yes I do have a message catalog for this entry

Comment: It is that message that is causing this error. It probably has a stray digit or something between the `%` and the `(`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your message catalog entry.

The `_(...)` call replaces your unicode value with one from the message catalog (if available), and it is *that* message that throws this exception. Swapping the `%` and the preceding space would do this, for example:

```
>>> '►% (user)s, random text here @[%(friend_id)s] more random text ◄◄◄'.decode('utf-8') % {'user':u'foo', 'friend_id': u'bar'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: unsupported format character '(' (0x28) at index 3
```